# "create table" statement is not working, the other code is perfectly working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a new subject and corresponding folder and a table for that
 subject but only create table statement is not working while other statements are working
 very well. If I am copying the "create table" statement directly into mysql then its
 working but facing problem in this code.

```
   if(isset($_GET['Subject'])) {
        $subj = $_GET['subject'];
        $re = "insert into branches(branch) values('$subj')";
        if(!mysql_query($re)) {
            echo "<h3>Dublicate Subject! or Error in inserting data</h3>";
        }
        else {
                mkdir("../$subj");
            $re = "create table $subj (id int(8) primary key auto_increment, sub_dir varchar(40) unique)";
            if(!mysql_query($re)) {
            echo "<h3>Cannot create Table named '$subj' but subject is inserted! First Delete it!</h3>";
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: No error message, but manual message: Cannot create Table named 'any_subject'... that's in the code.

Comment: Then get the real error message by using `mysql_error()`

Comment: Error message : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add (id int(8) primary key auto_increment, sub_dir varchar(40) unique)' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error message : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`add (id int(8) primary key auto_increment, sub_dir varchar(40) unique)`' at line 1

`ADD` is a MySQL reserved word. To use it as a database object, surround it with back ticks.

But it would be a better choice avoiding use of reserved words for database object names or expression names in calculation.

Change name of the table you want to create as appropriate and respecting the rules and naming conventions.

**Refer to**: [**MySQL Reserved Words**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use the echo statement to output the query you are attempting to run. Then you can test it yourself and find the problem. As another point, your query is failing because you have not added backticks around the table name.

Your code is very insecure and will result in sql injection. You need to use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape your table name.